# Dealing with nested struct access

Tags: c

What is the best way to avoid writing something like:

```
someDataStruct.longSubStructName.anotherLongName.theVariable = 
    someStruct.longSubStructName.anotherLongName.theVariable + 10;
```

Setters and getters would be a work around in oop programs. But what would be the best way to deal with this in for example C without having any objects?

Comment: In C you can use a pointer.

Comment: Never ever ever use ”getters” and ”setters”

Comment: @4386424 Thanks! Then I don’t understand the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Create a pointer to the variables in question:

```
int *someDataVar1 = &someDataStruct.longSubStructName.anotherLongName.theVariable;
int *someDataVar2 = &someStruct.longSubStructName.anotherLongName.theVariable;

*someDataVar1 = *someDataVar2 + 10;
```

If you're using a deeply nested field like this many times in a block of code, doing something like this can help to increase readability.  If you only need to use it once or twice however you're probably better off leaving it way it is.

Here's an example where such a construct might make sense:

```
for (clientNum = 0; clientNum < clientCount; clientNum++) {
    printf("name: %s\n", mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].name);
    printf("address: %s\n", mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].address);
    printf("identifier: %x\n", mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].identifier);
    printf("file count: %d\n", mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].fileCount);

    for (fileNum = 0; fileNum < mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].fileCount; fileNum++) {
        printf("filename: %s\n", mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].fileList[fileNum].fileName);
        printf("size: %d\n", mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].fileList[fileNum].size);
        printf("checksum: %d\n", mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].fileList[fileNum].checksum);
        mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].fileList[fileNum].printed++;
    }

    mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum].printed++;
}
```

Lots of verbose, repeated information here.  So much so it can make it difficult to see what you're actually working with.  This can be made more readable as follows:

```
for (clientNum = 0; clientNum < clientCount; clientNum++) {
    struct client *thisClient = &mainStructure.subStructure.clientList[clientNum];
    printf("name: %s\n", thisClient->name);
    printf("address: %s\n", thisClient->address);
    printf("identifier: %x\n", thisClient->identifier);
    printf("file count: %d\n", thisClient->fileCount);

    for (fileNum = 0; fileNum < thisClient->fileCount; fileNum++) {
        struct file *thisFile = &thisClient.fileList[fileNum];
        printf("filename: %s\n", thisFile->fileName);
        printf("size: %d\n", thisFile->size);
        printf("checksum: %d\n", thisFile->checksum);
        thisFile->printed++;
    }

    thisClient->printed++;
}
```

Comment: why not a reference?

Comment: @TimRandall This is C, not C++.

Comment: Accepted. However, I think you misread the original code. Different structures are being accessed.

Comment: Or create a pointer to the innermost struct, and use it to access the struct members.

Comment: @TimRandall Yes, I did miss that.  Fixed.

Comment: @4386427 Depends.  If a deeply nested field is used frequently enough in a given block of code, it may be worthwhile to create a pointer with a sufficiently descriptive name that can be used in its place.  In certain cases it could improve readability.

Comment: @4386427 It won't confuse things if named properly and restricted in scope.  I also have a hard time believing this can actually hurt performance, especially if one of the subfields is a pointer itself.  Sounds like a microoptimization.

Comment: @4386427 from a very short look, it introduces an extra multiply instruction: https://godbolt.org/g/X3vbUa

Comment: @FantasticMrFox when compiling with optimizations it seems to be the same: https://godbolt.org/g/NVqKfG -- with compiler optimizations off, it's going to do a much more 1-to-1 translation of the source than it would in "real" code.

Comment: This is *the* answer: type safe and efficient. Added benefit of this approach is that these short names can be used also in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your inner structs anonymous typedefs, you can use plan9 extensions to access the sub-struct's member directly (assuming there aren't any variable name conflicts).  **Disclaimer**: I do not really recommend this method as I prefer standard-conforming C, but figure I'd lob it out there because it does exist.  Here's an example of it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
   int x;
   int y;
} inner_struct1;

typedef struct{
   int v;
   int w;
} inner_struct2;

struct outer_struct {
   inner_struct1;
   inner_struct2;
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

int main(void)
{
   struct outer_struct os;
   os.x = 1;
   os.y = 2;
   os.v = 3;
   os.w = 4;
   os.a = 5;
   os.b = 6;
   os.c = 7;

   printf("inner_struct1.x: %d, inner_struct1.y: %d, inner_struct2.v: %d,
       inner_struct2.w: %d os.a: %d, os.b: %d, os.c: %d\n",
       os.x, os.y, os.v, os.w, os.a, os.b, os.c);
}
```

With gcc, you'd have to compile with either `-fplan9-extensions` or `-fms-extensions`.
clang does not have plan9, so only `-fms-extensions` will work.

Comment: I’m glad you added that disclaimer. This is really ugly... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo You know you're gonna go to bed tonight pondering what new possibilities are opened up to you with Plan9 extensions.  By morning, your mind will be so infected by Plan9 that you won't be able to make nested structs *without* the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer these operation inside a function with meaning full name and use inline.

```
inline void someFunctionNameAdd(int val)
{
    someDataStruct.longSubStructName.anotherLongName.theVariable = 
         someStruct.longSubStructName.anotherLongName.theVariable + val;
}
```

then call function someFunctionName(10);

Other way use define macro:

```
#define SOME_MEANINGFULLNAME \
          someDataStruct.longSubStructName.anotherLongName.theVariable
```

then:
SOME_MEANINGFULLNAME+=10;

Comment: While `SOME_MEANINGFULLNAME` works, it's horrible because it leaks out of scope. It should be only considered as a last resort.